# SSIS Import data that is NOT columnar into SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, text, import, ssis

I am fairly new to SSIS and need a little help getting started.  I have several reports that come out of our mainframe.  The reports are not in a columnar format.  The date record is at the top then there might be some initial data then there might be a little more.  So I need to read in each line look to see what the text reads and figure out if I need the data or move to the next row.

This is a VERY rough example of what the report I want to import into a SQL table.

> ```
> DATE:  01/08/2020                   FACILITY NAME                             PAGE1
>
>                  REVENUE USAGE                     FOR ACCOUNTING PERIOD 02
>    ----TOTAL----  ----TOTAL----  ----OTHER----  ----INSURANCE----  ----INSURANCE2----  
>
> SERVICE CODE - 123456789  DESCRIPTION:  WIDGETS
> CURR                 2,077
>  IP          0.0000      3     2,345     0.00       
>                      143
>  OP          0.0000      2     1,231     0.00
>
> YTD                    5
>    IP         0.0000
>                        76 
>    OP         0.0000   
> etc . . . .. .
> SERVICE CODE
> ```

After the SERVICE CODE the data will start to repeat like it is above.  This is the basic idea of a report.

I want to get the **Date** then the **Service Code, Description, Current IP Volume, Current IP Dollar, Current OP Volume, Current OP Dollar, YTD IP Volume, YTD IP Dollar, YTD OP Volume, YTD OP Dollar** . . then repeat.

***Just to clarify, I am not asking anyone to do this for me.  I want to learn how to do this.  I have looked on how to do this but every example I have looked at talks about doing this with a CSV, tab, or Excel file.  i do not have that type of file so I was asking what I need to look at. I currently use Monarch to format the file, but again I want to learn more about SSIS and this is a perfect way to learn.  Asking the vendor to redo the report is not an option plus I want to learn how to do this.  Thank you I just wanted to get that out there.***

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Rodger

Comment: In short, you'll likely going to need to use a script transformation. This isnt something we can help with with the little we have, and asking us to do the whole thing would be a big ask. I suggest starting and looking up the subject, and when you get stuck, asking questions about that.

Comment: This appears to be a task that you would want to do in a pre-processing program outside of SQL or SSIS that would build a file you can import in.  You can use a script task I suppose, but those are a handful to try and debug.

Comment: Script task would be the wrong choice, @JMabee , you'll want a Script Transformation. Although similar, they are very different.

Comment: If I were you I would contact whoever owns the reports that come out of the mainframe, and ask if it is possible to get the data in a more consumable format. The data most like comes from tables, so reformatting the data twice only to get it back into tables seems very inefficient. Failing that, you will, as has been suggested, need to use a script task or similar, along with a StreamReader to process the file.

Comment: @Larnu I would disagree that a script task is the *wrong* choice. If you are comfortable with c# or vb.NET it is much less faffing around to do the entire ETL within a single script task with a StreamReader and SqlBulkCopy than it would be to separate the package into flat file source, script component, and OLE DB destination. Unless there is some significant down-side to the script task that I am not aware of, I think it is personal preference rather than right and wrong. My preference would be the former as I find c# significantly more appealing and flexible than most things in SSIS.

Comment: A script transformation *does* use C# @GarethD (or VB.net), so not sure what you're point is there. You're effectively saying you'd rather use C# instead of C#. You use use the Script on the Data Flow as a source, and define the data set and how-to read it there. they are great for stuff like this because you program (in a .Net language) exactly how to read it. A Script task doesn't have the same functionality to define a data flow; so is less designed for the task.

Comment: Yes, but it has to tie in with a flat file source, and then a destination, you have to configure inputs and outputs, all of which (to me at least) is a lot of arsing around for the same end result. If you do it all in a script task you don't have to do this, you read from your stream reader and write to your server in the same place, so much simpler (again, in my opinion). So my point is, that I don't think it is the **wrong** choice, just a different choice.

Comment: Seems just a conflict of opinion then @GarethD . :)

Comment: Short answers. Can this be done with SSIS - probably with great difficulty. Can YOU do this in SSIS - probably not. Learning and implementing a task using SSIS with well-structured data and little additional transformation logic is not too difficult. But this approach goes way beyond that. As already suggested, write a preprocessor in a language you do know as your first step after you understand (and define) how to transform your report into your database schema.

Comment: You should also investigate whether your mainframe can export the desired information in a more usable format. I will bet that it can.

Comment: @ Lamu and GarethD - I am just wanting to learn more about what I can do with SSIS and thought this would be the perfect way to learn.  I learn best when I can take something that I currently do and automate it.  I will look at Script Task and Transform and StreamReader.  I am sure I will have more questions once I get into it more.  Thank you both!!!  This is perfect!!

Comment: I've had to deal with something similar in the past.  The way we solved it was load each line into a nvarchar(max) column along with line number using SSIS and then parsed the data in tsql.   Not the most elegant solution but it got i done.

Comment: Way back in the day we used a program called Monarch, which worked by anchoring certain text. Good Luck!!! I guess if i finished reading your question I would know that is how you currently do it

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments, you *could* do this using a script task. The basics steps are:

1. Define a [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netframework-4.8) to store your data.
2. Use a [StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netframework-4.8) to read your report.
3. Process this using a combination of conditionals, [String Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8), and [parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=netframework-4.8) to extract the relevant fields from the relevant line:
4. Write the DataTable to the database using [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=netframework-4.8)

The following would go inside your Main method in your script task:

```cs
//Define a table to store your data 
var table = new DataTable
{
    Columns = 
    { 
        { "ServiceCode", typeof(string) }, 
        { "Description", typeof(string) }, 
        { "CurrentIPVolume", typeof(int) },
        { "CurrentIPDollar,", typeof(decimal) },
        { "CurrentOPVolume", typeof(int) },
        { "CurrentOPDollar", typeof(decimal) },
        { "YTDIPVolume", typeof(int) },
        { "YTDIPDollar,", typeof(decimal) },
        { "YTDOPVolume", typeof(int) },
        { "YTDOPDollar", typeof(decimal) } 
    }
};

var filePath = @"Your File Path";
using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    string line = null;
    DataRow row = null;

    // As YTD and Curr are identical, we will need a flag later to mark our position within the record
    bool ytdFlag= false; 

    //Loop through every line in the file 
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        //if the line is blank, move on to the next
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)
            continue;

        // If the line starts with service code, then it marks the start of a new record
        if (line.StartsWith("SERVICE CODE"))
        {
            //If the current value for row is not null then this is
            //not the first record, so we need to add the previous 
            //record to the tale before continuing              
            if (row != null)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(row);
                ytdFlag= false; // New record, reset YTD flag
            }
            row = table.NewRow();

            //Split the line now based on known values:
            var tokens = line.Split(new string[] { "SERVICE CODE - ", "DESCRIPTION: "}, StringSplitOptions.None);

            row[0] = tokens[0];
            row[1] = tokens[1]; 
        }

        if (line.StartsWith("CURR"))
        {
            //Process the row --> "CURR                 2,077"
            //Not sure what 2,077 is, but this will parse it
            int i = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(line.Substring(4).Trim().Replace(",", ""), out i))
            {
                //Do something with your int
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }

        }

        if (line.StartsWith(" IP"))
        {
            //Start at after IP then split the line into the 4 numbers
            var tokens = line.Substring(3).Split(new [] { " "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            //If we have gone past the CURR record, then at to YTD Columns
            if (ytdFlag)
            {
                row[6] = int.Parse(tokens[1]);
                row[7] = decimal.Parse(tokens[1]);
            }
            //Otherwise we are still in the CURR section:
            else
            {
                row[2] = int.Parse(tokens[1]);
                row[3] = decimal.Parse(tokens[1]);
            }
        }
        if (line.StartsWith(" OP"))
        {
            //Start at after OP then split the line into the 4 numbers
            var tokens = line.Substring(3).Split(new [] { " "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            //If we have gone past the CURR record, then at to YTD Columns
            if (ytdFlag)
            {
                row[8] = int.Parse(tokens[1]);
                row[9] = decimal.Parse(tokens[1]);
            }
            //Otherwise we are still in the CURR section:
            else
            {
                row[4] = int.Parse(tokens[1]);
                row[5] = decimal.Parse(tokens[1]);
            }

            //After we have processed an OP record, we must set the YTD Flag to true.
            //Doesn't matter if it is the YTD OP record, since the flag will be reset
            //By the next line that starts with SERVICE CODE anyway
            ytdFlag= true;
        }
    }
}

//Now that we have processed the file, we can write the data to a database
using (var sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy("Your Connection String"))
{
    sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.YourTable";

    //If necessary add column mappings, but if your DataTable matches your database table
    //then this is not required

    sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
}
```

This is a very quick example, far from the finished article, and I have done little or no testing, but it should give you the gist of how it *could* be done, and get you started on one possible solution.

It can definitely be cleaned up and refactored, but I have tried to make it as clear as possible what is going on, rather than trying to write the most efficient code ever. It should also (hopefully) demonstrate what a monumental pain this is to do, and very minor report changes things like an extra space be "OP" will break the whole thing.

So again, I would re-iterate, if you can get the data in a standard flat file format, with one line per record, you should. I do however appreciate that sometimes these things are out of your control, and I have had to write incredibly ugly import routines like this in the past, so I feel your pain if you can't get the data in a consumable format.

Comment: WOW this is awesome.  Thank you this will help me so much!!!  I look forward to working on this over the weekend.  AGAIN THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Thank you again.  This is just what I needed to get started.  I see I have a lot more work to do after looking at this more.  Each "Section" has 4 lines to evaluate.Current_Total, IP, OP, YTD_Total, YTD_IP, YTD_OP